# Dispatching action from Background script using webext-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux, webext-redux

I'm working on a Chrome Extension in React that calls an async function on the background script.  To do so, the user clicks a button on the content script that triggers this function.  While the script is executing, the button shows a loading icon and should revert when the background script is complete.  I'm using webext-redux for Redux in the extension: https://github.com/tshaddix/webext-redux

I haven't got this working properly, so here's some pseudo code that works if the browser window running the content script stays open

**Content Script**

```
componentDidMount() {
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        (request) => {
            if(request.action === "syncComplete") {
                this.props.dispatch(syncing(false))
            }
        });
}

sync() {
  this.props.dispatch(syncing(true));
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "sync"});
}

render() {
  <a onClick={() => this.sync()}>
    {this.props.syncing ? (<span><Icon type="loading" /> Syncing...</span>) : "Force Sync" }
  </a>
}
```

**Background Script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  if(request.action === "sync") startImport();
  return true
});

async function startImport() {
     ...
  // Large async function
  // On complete or fail do:
  chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://example.com/*"}, (tabs) => {
      for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {action: "syncComplete"});
      }
  });
}
```

The problem I face though, is since my async function is running in the background script (intentional so the user can continue to navigate around the site the content script is on), if a user closes the content script tab and the background script completes, there is no content script running to receive the Chrome message to dispatch the sync action.  As such, the whole extension gets stuck in a permanent "loading" state on the button.

Does anyone know how I can tackle this, or if it is possible to dispatch an action from the background script?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean near "there is content script to receive the Chrome message to dispatch the sync action". I think you meant "there is **no**..."?

Comment: Ah yes, typo.  There is NO content script running

Comment: Then I don't see any way in which your extension could be stuck in a loading state, as you state it. For the simple reason, that, even though that particular tab was closed, the other tabs (`"https://example.com/*"`) will indeed receive the `syncComplete` message.

Comment: @GaurangTandon the content script only runs on a certain domain. If the user hits sync, and closes the tab on that domain, the background script still continues to run the function (this is correct as the function is syncing a a 3rd parties website with another API).    However since the user has closed that tab for the domain, the syncComplete message is never received

Answer (score 0):

Once the tab is closed, the content script instance along with it is also gone and there is no way to dispatch the action from the background page to that content script anymore. (Even if the user does Ctrl-Shift-T for that tab, it will have a new tabid.)

You mention that your extension gets stuck in a "loading state". One way to fix this would be to maintain a flag in the `localStorage` of the background page, like `localStorage.hasPendingUpdate`. The next time you load a `example.com` tab, message the background page asking if there is any pending update. If there is, the background page would send that tab the pending update.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.  The only issue I then have is if the user exits Chrome mid-sync, LocalStorage will always still be "syncing" and again we're stuck

Comment: @K20GH I agree, in that case, you could store another flag for the background page too.

Answer (score 0):

A note from personal experience for those who now want to start creating browser extensions and are figuring out how to build a proper store.

Don't use webext-redux!!!

It was the "easiest" but not the optimal solution (because we play the repository for each tab). And now it's a terrible solution because it has terrible support (the last update was 2 years ago).

You can look towards [Chrome Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage) as a solution.